# Bootstrap Popover: It disappears instead of staying active

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, popover

I'm dealing with Bootstrap popovers and i'm getting stuck. When i click the button, the popover shows and quickly it disappears again. It doesn't stay visible.

Besides, when i always click the button and the popover shows, a image placed in the web blinks, which is very strange. I have been trying different popover configurations but it's weird and i don't get it work.

Btw, i'm using Ruby on Rails and the Bootstrap/jQuery gem.

Here it is my code:

```
<div class="span9">
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>#</th>
           <th>Domain</th>
           <th>API KEY</th>
           <th>API SECRET</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>1</td>
           <td>http://www.example.com</td>
           <td>29383947382</td>
           <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn-warning" id="api_secret" rel="popover" data-content="b23v2v3l3pdns9282b3v2g3b2" data-original-title="Your API SECRET:">Show</a></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And these Javascript lines at the bottom of the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

// Popovers
$('#api_secret').popover({
    animation: false
});

// Tabs
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
});

});

</script>
```

Comment: I think you are doing the popover twice: once through the `rel` attribute and once through the JavaScript. Try removing the `rel=popover` from the HTML.

Comment: Removed, and it's still happening the same.